# Eureka Client Registered with Container IP in ECS Fargate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka, aws-fargate

We deployed Spring Boot services in the ECS Fargate with Eureka Registry Service, Gateway Service and a few business services. In the Eureka registry page all the client services registered were showing same IP (could be container IP).

Please share what configuration should be provided to register with ECS task private ip instead of container IP. Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Eureka Service Application Properties:**

```
server.port=8080
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Eureka Client Service Application Properties**

```
server.port=8766
spring.application.name= client-service
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address= true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone= <eureka-ecs-ip>:8080
eureka.instance.lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds=30
```

Comment: I would try
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.ip-address=<task address>

Comment: Hi Josh, Yes we have mentioned prefer-ip-address property,. If I am not wrong task-ip-address is dynamic right.

Comment: Correct and that is a problem I didn't think about. Maybe try https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/docs/current/reference/html/#using-eureka-on-aws

Comment: Ok Josh, will give a try and update you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved by adding the below code to SpringBootApplication source. This block picks update host IP address (not container) and overrides the config property/yaml settings.

```
    @Bean
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils){

        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
        String ip = null;
        try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
       
        config.setIpAddress(ip);
        config.setPreferIpAddress(true);
          

        return config;
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone that still can't fix it with the accepted answer:

I also had to set secure/non-secure port in `config` (and enable it).